# Ошибка с неуправляемой памятью

Tags: c#, pinvoke

Есть библиотека на c++ и документация к ней. В целом с ней могу работать, но с некоторыми функциями проблема.

В документации:

```
LONG CLSCRF_MifareStandard_AuthKey( IN LPVOID pReader,
    IN BYTE bKeyType, 
    IN LPBYTE pbUID, 
    IN DWORD dwSector, 
    IN LPBYTE pbCodedKey );
```

Подключаю библиотеку:

```
[DllImport(ClscrflDll)]
public static extern uint CLSCRF_MifareStandard_AuthKey(IntPtr pReader, byte bKeyType, IntPtr pbUID, uint dwSector, IntPtr pbCodedKey);
```

К примеру, UID - это массив байт, в IntPrt перевожу его так:

```
var pbUID = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(UID.Length);
Marshal.Copy(UID, 0, pbUID, UID.Length);
```

С остальными типами, вроде всё понятно.
В итоге при вызове функции получаю ошибку:

> Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто
>   свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена.

Есть подозрения что это что-то с pbCodedKey. Это ключ авторизации. Его получаю я другой функцией:

```
[DllImport(ClscrflDll)]
public static extern uint CLSCRF_MifareStandard_HostCodeKey(IntPtr pReader, IntPtr pbUncoded, ref IntPtr pbCoded);
///----------
byte[] key = new byte[6] { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };
var pbKey = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(key.Length);
Marshal.Copy(key, 0, pbKey, key.Length);

var _key = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(12);
var err = Clscrfl.CLSCRF_MifareStandard_HostCodeKey(pReader, pbKey, ref _key);
```

Её описание:

```
LONG CLSCRF_MifareStandard_HostCodeKey( IN LPVOID pReader,
IN LPBYTE pbUncoded,
OUT LPBYTE pbCoded );
```

В чём может быть проблема, хотя бы примерно?

Comment: Каким образом вы превратили `OUT LPBYTE pbCoded` в `ref IntPtr pbCoded`? Был указатель на буфер - стал указатель на указатель.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Это и была моя ошибка, которая не давала авторизоваться.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
//Не забывайте  System.Runtime.InteropServices;  
[DllImport("Clscrfl.dll")]//подозреваю муки с ней
/*
LONG CLSCRF_MifareStandard_AuthKey( IN LPVOID pReader,
    IN BYTE bKeyType, 
    IN LPBYTE pbUID, 
    IN DWORD dwSector, 
    IN LPBYTE pbCodedKey );
*/

public static extern int CLSCRF_MifareStandard_AuthKey(  
[In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int pReader,  
byte bKeyType,  
[In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 4)] byte[] pbUID, //Mifare Classic only  
int dwSector,
[In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 12)] byte[] pbCodedKey);
```

В данном случае для вызова функции не требуется сложный маршаллинг

Comment: Welcome to `Stackoverflow in russian`! Sorry, but answers only in russian allowed. Please, translate you answer to russian and format your code)

Comment: А размер pReader тут не напутан? Лучше его как IntPtr оставить...

Comment: Да и DWORD правильнее как uint записывать.

Comment: Нормально работает -  проверено

Comment: Единственно проект надо для 32битной платформы строить